# How can I get an element by Id or class in a Google Script?

Tags: javascript

For a project I am working on I want to extract all EAN numbers from a list of different URL's in Google Sheet.

Now I am using the URL Fetch app method to get the HTML of the link but when I want to select the element I want to use in my script, I get the following error:

TypeError: html.getElementById is not a function

My code

```
function scrapeWebsite() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/p/azul-tuin-van-de-koningin-bordspel/9300000094065315/?promo=main_860_product_4&bltgh=kj5mIYO78dnIY1vUCvxPbg.18_19.24.ProductTitle');
  var html = response.getContentText();
  var element = html.getElementById('test')
}
```

Comment: `getContentText` returns text, not a DOM. You'll need to convert it first. [`DOMParser.parseFromString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `await` that fetch. Then take the response and `.innerHTML` it into a placeholder element like below:

```
async function scrapeWebsite() {
let response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/p/azul-tuin-van-de-koningin-bordspel/9300000094065315/?promo=main_860_product_4&bltgh=kj5mIYO78dnIY1vUCvxPbg.18_19.24.ProductTitle');
let html = response.text();
let element = html.getElementById('test')
let el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = response;
}
```